# Android- Fetch the contacts based on contact id greater than some value

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

> i want to fetch the contacts from android periodically. for that i
>   want to something like this. i am taking all the conatcts from the
>   android and store it in my local db. so i will store last contact id.
>   so next time on wards if any contacts added , i need to get those
>   contacts only so for that purpose i want to fetch the contact id
>   greater than last time fetched contact id. how can write the query for
>   content resolver to fetch the contacts some thing like.

```
Select * from tablename where id > 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor  cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, // this will be the columns selection               
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + ">100", // this is where you add the "where" part of the query, id is 1 in this case
                        null, // where args, you are skipping these               
                        null); // sort order
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
             while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));   
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)).trim();

             }
        }
```

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: @DArO Sry i forgot to mention here. there Contact_ID Column type is String. if i compare with string variable which contains the last contact id, it is giving no such column exception.

Comment: ContactsContract.Contacts._ID has a value of "_id" which is the name of the id column in every content provider table (per specification). So the query you are making in that specific part is what comes after "where" which in the case above would be where _id > 100